# SQL Union and Group By(group by specific value but show all)

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

[image]

How can i merge this tables with specific group by value. I need to group this by Accomplishment Date, ETR Date,Equipment Name, Project and Operator Name, but need ETR Actual Hour, Accomplishment Actual Hour etc. still showing in the same row.

Here is my sample query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT '' as AccomplishmentDate, ETRDate, ProjectName,EquipmentName, 0 as 
        AccomplishmentActualHour, ETRActualHour FROM Table1

   UNION

   SELECT AccomplishmentDate, '' as ETRDate, ProjectName,,EquipmentName,
        AccomplishmentActualHour,0 as ETRActualHour FROM Table1

)as Transaction
```

Comment: i assume you meant SQL Server when you said MS SQL and tagged the question as such.

Comment: did you try adding a group by clause to your query?

Comment: If I use group by, all i can get is the value included in the group by clause right?Like ProjectName, EquipmentName. How about  ETR Actual Hour or other columns that i need to show?All i need is to merge two rows into one by grouping it using ProjectName or EquipmentName but shows other values not in the group? Sorry this is my first time in stackoverflow:)

Comment: Hello please see my latest image to make it clear.thanks!

Comment: Using MAX(neededcolumn) for the columns you want may give you the desired result. You can get an aggregate from each non-grouped column, and you’ll have to decide what aggregate (SUM or MAX perhaps) is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Select the name or column you want. Don't use *. It selects all the attributes
like Select Accomplisment..... from(select * from table union select * from table